# Chart.js: trouble with resizing on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

With this code, my chart is resizing when I drag the window, but not when I press the maximize button on windows or the full screen button on mac. Is this just a chart.js problem? Here is my JS for resizing the chart.

```js
// -- draw the chart ---
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ctx = null;
  chart= null;
  var width = 0;
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  setTimeout(function(){
    width = $('##chart').parent().width();
    $('##chart').attr("width",width-30);
    ctx = $("##chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    chart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);

    // --- resize ---
    $( window ).resize(function() {
      var newScreenWidth = $(window).width();
      if(screenWidth != newScreenWidth){
        width = $('##chart').parent().width();
        $('##chart').replaceWith('<canvas id="chart" width="650" height="175"></canvas>');
        $('##chart').attr("width",width-30);
        ctx = $("##chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        chart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);    
      }
    });
  },500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I never had resize problem with chart.js, and you don't need to subscribe to the resize event because the resize is already handled by chart.js depending on the size of the canvas container. Do you have this issue when you browse working chart.js websites with this mac ?

from [chartjs.org](http://chartjs.org):

> Chart.js will resize your chart if the browser changes size, along with providing the perfect scale granularity for that size

And btw please take a look at your console, `$('##chart')` is not a valid jQuery selector and should produce an error. I don't know how the code you posted could work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure why, but when I don't have the resize function, chart.js does not resize for me. Maybe they have made updates since we first started using it. It is weird because this exact function works on other pages for us. The double # is because we are using cold fusion.

Comment: Ok I didn't know cold fusion, if you manage to isolate your issue in a JSFiddle we can see what's going on. You can also check if you still have this issue with a recent version of chart.js.